# Can openlayers 3 select the closest feature if there are two on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers-3

I'm using the ol.source.Vector.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate function to get the closest feature to the mouse, I believe this is similar to one of the ol3 examples.

When on the map there exists a LineSegment and a Point, where the point coordinates are also in the line segment coordinate list, I can't reliably count on the point being detected by the getClosestFeatureToCoordinate method.  I think it basically turns into which feature is listed first in an internal list.

I want to use an arbitrary small extent and try selecting all the features in the extent (forEachFeatureInExtent), then sorting them by some other criteria.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Some time ago I've made [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zbqKeJ4lXQ8C60TC4fza?p=preview), take a look if it's your case.

Comment: This is not quite the same situation, but you can see if you move the mouse in over the intersection of the line feature and the poly feature, for me, the line is added to the overlay, and the poly feature is not, until the mouse passes over it.  If the poly were a point instead, would it ever be added?

Comment: We could build a fiddle together. I'm not sure about your case.